# regex match after decimal number (python re)

Tags: python-re

Looking to cleave off trailing text, if any, from a string that has '@' immediately followed by a decimal number using re.split in Python. Examples:

myString1 = 'random text @2.25 possibly more text'

myString2 = 'random text @-1.50 possibly more text'

myString3 = 'random text @-.50'

Desired output:

1: 'random text @2.25'

2: 'random text @-1.50'

3: 'random text @-.50'

What I tried:

```
test = re.split('(?<=@[0-9]+.[0-9]+)', myString)[0]
```

`?<=` gets me match after. Then `@[0-9]` gets me the ampersand and first number match. Since the number could be more than 1 digit long before the decimal point, I add the '+', as in `[0-9]+` and this fails with a 'look behind' error.

Is what I'm trying to do possible with re.split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to split here, I would instead do an `re.search` for the appropriate pattern:

```py
inp = ["random text @2.25 possibly more text", "random text @-1.50 possibly more text", "random text @-.50"]
output = [re.search(r'^.*?@-?\d*(?:\.\d+)?', x).group() for x in inp]
print(output)  # ['random text @2.25', 'random text @-1.50', 'random text @-.50']
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

- `^` from the start of the string
- `.*?` match all content, leading up to the nearest
- `@`
- `-?` optional minus sign
- `\d*` zero or more digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` optional decimal component

Comment: wunderbar! Thanks for a solution and for explaining the pattern!